# c++ upper value calculation

Tags: c++, rounding

I have a double variable double dub1. In case it is integer multiple of 15, I want to get the result of division (e.g. 30/15 -> 2 ok). In case it is not integer multiple, I want to round it to upper value (e.g. 20/15 -> 2 ok). How should I handle the first part intelegently.

```
int divres = dub1/15; //For the second part
divres++;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do floating point rounding with a bias (always round up or down)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685907/how-do-i-do-floating-point-rounding-with-a-bias-always-round-up-or-down)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`std::ceil`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) function, located in `<cmath>`:

```
int divres = static_cast<int>(std::ceil(dub1/15));
```

OK, without `ceil`, you could use [`std::fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) the following way:

```
int divres = dub1/15;
if (std::fmod(dub1, 15) != 0) {
    divres++;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to use ceil.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg He said that `dub1` is a `double`, which is floating point.

Comment: @AvbAvb then what do you want?

Comment: @AvbAvb Why don't you want to use it? It does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Barmar maybe he doesn't want to use libarary functions.

Comment: @Tahlil, that doesn't make any sense. Why not?

Comment: Thanks for both options

Comment: Like handling precision.

Answer (score 0):

```
int divres = dub1/15; //For the second part
if(dub1 - (15*divres) >.000001) // check to see if it is not equal
   divres++;
```